# woocommerce storefront width mobile screen issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, width, screen, storefront

I have a serious problem with certain parts of the woocommerce storefront's responsive theme when using mobile screen devices. I am unable to use 100% of the width of the mobile device’s screen for the related products area. I’d like the 2 columns to take advantage of the screen’s width. Can anyone help me with the css code, please? See image below

[image: CSS Code]

The same applies to the widget section below.

[image: WP Content]

Can please anyone help?

The link for the page I need help with is https://www.samuelsotiega.com/product/sunrise-at-el-prado/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using css you can "fix"

```
.sp-designer .widget-area .widget {
     margin-right: 0; }

.sp-designer ul.products li.product {
        margin-right: 9px;
}
```

If need use !important to override rules